# What does happen if we use a delta function for density on the De Broglie–Bohm theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions, bohmian-mechanics

I was reading [Pilot wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory) and [De Broglie–Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) pages on Wikipedia that I found how similar they are comparing to classical physics and I wondered what happens if we just replace the density with a delta function,

$$\rho=q \delta^3(\pmb r-\pmb r') =\frac{-q}{4\pi}  \nabla.(\nabla \frac{1}{\vert\pmb r-\pmb r'\vert} )  $$

On the wave function:

$$\Psi=\sqrt \rho \mathit exp (iS/\hbar)$$

Comment: FWIW, a square root of a Dirac delta function does not make sense.

Comment: @Qmechanic Maybe you are right but I think we can define the square root of a Laplacian.

Comment: @MartinSpinoza, you can, but it has nothing to do with $\sqrt{\rho}$. The square root of the Laplacian is taken in the sense of composition of linear operators.